# jQuery eval of ajax inline script not throwing errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, debugging, firebug

[Debugging Ajax code with Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606794/debugging-ajax-code-with-firebug)

This question is quite similar, though old and without real answers.

I'm currently putting together an app that has scripts that get loaded in with an ajax request.

An example:

```
var main = _main.get();
main.load( someurl );
```

Where someurl is a page that contains an inline script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function(){
    var activities = new activities();
    activities.init();
});
</script>
```

jQuery will do a line by line eval of js that lives in inline script tags. The problem is, I get no errors or any information whatsoever in firebug when something goes awry.

Does anyone have a good solution for this? Or a better practice for loading pages which contain javascript functionality?

Edit: A little progress... so at the top of the page that is being loaded in via ajax, I have another script that was being included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/pages/activities.js"></script>
```

When I moved the inline $(document).ready() code in the page to the end of this included file, instead, syntax errors were now properly getting thrown.

As an aside, I threw a console.log() into the inline script tag, and it was being logged just fine. I also tried removing the $(document).ready() altogether, and also switching it out for a $(window).load() event. No difference. May have something to do with the inline scripts dependency on the included activities.js, I guess.

:: shakes head :: javascript can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ for lazy loading Javascript or for getting html content http://api.jquery.com/load/

respectively:

```
$.getScript('path/to/file.js');
```

.. and

```
$('#content-wrap').load('path/to/html/file.html');
```

Both of theses methods are wraps around http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and have optional callback function parameters.