# In IE7 how can we Inspect Element and change the css properties

Tags: html, css, debugging, internet-explorer-7

Roughly I have spent 2 hours and concert many question answers regarding IE7 debugging tools as well as methods, I have installed 'firebug lite', 'debuggarBar' and used also Developer Tools

But my problem is that I have ajax call and load data into popup box that is not shown in view sourse and as well as in any debugger!

Please would you refer me any method or tool from where I can change the ajax called data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may like to check out this thread here

[Debugging Ajax code with Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606794/debugging-ajax-code-with-firebug). And also this video

www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M.

There is also a clear description here on this article

http://www.dev4press.com/2010/tutorials/wordpress/various/use-firebug-to-track-ajax-requests-and-responses/

Comment: Actually IE7 does't support firebug and for firebug lite no such more details